# jQuery Tablesorter add alt attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

is there a way to modify jQuery Tablesorter where I can add alt attribute on each table cell with the innerText of that cell? This will be very helpful for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can add any alternative table cell text to the table cell's `data-text` attribute

```
<td data-text="21">Twenty-one</td>
```

If you want to modify the data attribute that is used, change it in the [`textAttribute` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textattribute)

```
$('table').tablesorter({
  textAttribute : 'data-content'
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Just what I needed. For 508 compliance I need a screen reader to be able to read the content inside the cell, so I am going to add a title to each of the cells. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend modifying some external code. Instead consider adding some code after the tablesorter call. For example, if your table id is `myTable`, you could do this:

```
$("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
$("#myTable td").each(function() { $(this).attr("alt", $(this).text()); });
```

---

On a side note, `alt` is not a valid attribute for a `td` tag. It should be used only with `img` and `area` tags (and optionally with `input` and `applet`). If you are saving the text there for later use, you may want to use a `data-` attribute instead of `alt`.